# Get web page source

Tags: ruby, shell, firefox

I am trying to get a web page source.
I used:

```
 $ curl --user name:password www.example.com
```

but this gives me the page source of the login page. I want to get the page source after logging in.

I also tried wget but to no success.

I can't use nokogiri and other ruby gems, etc.

Is there any way I can use firefox from the command line to get the page source or is there any other way to get the page source?

Thanks

Comment: This probably invovles dealing with a session. Honestly, I'd recommend using a web mechanization package, but if you can't do that, it's hard to help you without such little information.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can use firefox from the command line to get the page source...

You can script Firefox (among other browsers) through [Selenium WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted). For Ruby bindings, see [RubyBindings](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings).

---

**Edit:** You say you can't use "other Ruby gems," so I'm guessing Selenium Web Driver isn't an option. There's also [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/), which is a Firefox extension you can use and basically record a macro of yourself logging in. You can then call the test from the command line. This may or may not help, depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

---

Alternatively, you could login with cURL by [sending a POST request](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request) with the values you need. If you need to get the source of anything but the first page that comes back after the request, you'd need to use the `--cookie-jar` option to save your session for the subsequent request.